# Fill Multiple ComboBox With Array Data From MySql Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm very basic on vb.net and I have an issue with MySQL and Combobox. Let say I have data in MySQL like this:

```
   ID - Name 
   1  - Jack
   2  - Smith
   3  - John
   4  - Nick
```

I have let say 4 ComboBox and I want to fill these data to `Combobox1.SelectedText with value 1` for ID 1 Jack, `Combobox2.SelectedText with value 2` for ID 2 Smith, and so on. How to pass this with For Each or something. I'm confused about searching for an answer in StackOverflow and Google.
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you want 4 combo boxes in that scenario and not just each db entry as a text/value pair in a single combo box?

Comment: Are you going to fill each combobox with the same data; the complete list of names? Then have a different name selected in each combobox? It is hard for me to imagine a use case for this.

Comment: You won't be using SelectedText for a start. If you really have database data to display in multiple ComboBoxes then you simply populate a DataTable, bind it to multiple BindingSources, and then bind each of them to a ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

To fill a single combobox with your data do the following.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Function GetUsers() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select ID, Name From users;")
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub FillUsersCombo()
    Dim dt = GetUsers()
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
End Sub
```

You can access the data with `ComboBox1.Text` for the Name and `ComboBox1.SelectedValue` for the ID.

If you want to fill 3 more just repeat and set the `.Text` property of each box.

**EDIT**
As per comment by @CaiusJard

```
Private Function GetUsers() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select ID, Name From users;", ConStr)
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: `Using da as New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd, constr)` `da.Fill(dt)` `End Using` `Return dt` is more succinct

Comment: In addition, `DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row` can be used to retrieve the underlying row, which can give all the properties, not just the display/value

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, but you are creating an additional object. I assume that the adapter creates the connection so you have a connection, command and adapter.

Comment: Have you read the reference source for DataTable.Load?

Comment: @CaiusJard Just did and I see that an Adapter is loaded internally. I never noticed the Constructor of the adapter that takes a connection string. Clever and definitely more concise. Thanks. Can we skip both the command and the connection as long as no additional properties need to be set.